# Is it possible to check if method is declared in a group of classes?

Tags: java, unit-testing, archunit

I'm using ArchUnit and I want to check if all classes residing in a package declare one only public method called `execute`. I have this code:

```
JavaClasses importedClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages("my.package");        
methods().that().arePublic().should().haveName("execute").check(importedClasses);
```

It works but I would like this test to fail when `execute` method is absent in any class. With my code, test passes because all public methods (zero) actually have name "execute".

Comment: Did [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66162572/13134095) solve your problem? If so, it would be nice to mark it as accepted, as your question otherwise still appears as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test classes, you have to base your `ArchRule` on them (not on the methods that might not exist). You can use a [custom condition](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_creating_custom_rules) to count public methods and test their names, e.g. like this:

```java
ArchRule rule = classes()
    .that().resideInAPackage("my.package")
    .should(new ArchCondition<JavaClass>("have exactly one public method named 'execute'") {
        @Override
        public void check(JavaClass javaClass, ConditionEvents events) {
            List<JavaMethod> publicMethods = javaClass.getMethods().stream()
                    .filter(javaMethod -> javaMethod.getModifiers().contains(PUBLIC))
                    .collect(toList());
            boolean satisfied = false;
            String message = javaClass.getName() + " contains " + publicMethods.size() + " public method";
            if (publicMethods.size() == 1) {
                JavaMethod method = publicMethods.get(0);
                satisfied = method.getName().equals("execute");
                message += " named '" + method.getName() + "' " + method.getSourceCodeLocation();
            } else {
                message += "s " + javaClass.getSourceCodeLocation();
            }
            events.add(new SimpleConditionEvent(javaClass, satisfied, message));
        }
    });
```